# Read array of [Object object] elements in Java

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I want to send an array of objects to my backend. I use axios for this. The backend is called but I only get an array of [Object object] elements.

Frontend:

[image]

Backend:

```
@PostMapping("/neuerEintrag")
public String neuerEintrag(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam("zugeordnet") List<?> 
zugeordnet,..) {

....

}
```

Result in Backend:

> [[object Object], [object Object]]

Comment: Next time please post the code for the axios call, it's literally the single most important thing here and you posted everything but that :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send an object instead of a JSON string. If the object you're trying to send is in the variable `data`, you'll need to wrap it in `JSON.stringify` where you use it within the axios call

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```